# Rolling sum with two conditions

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I'm developing a ms-access database for the company i'm in, mainly for the purpose of keeping employee records, paid leaves and monthly attendance, however there's a hitch i haven't figured out yet.

I have the paid leave table columns set up as follows:

```
|ID|Month|Current_Leave|Earned_Leave|Absences|New_Leave|
```

ID+Month are set as the primary key for the table

I want this table to hold multiple employees' Leave records for multiple months, and i've set New_Leave to be a calculated field where:

```
(current_leave +  earned_leave - absences = new_leave)
```

However i can't figure out how to work around creating a new record that will include duplicate IDs (same employee) for the following month where Current_Leave = previous month's New_Leave

For example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkO9C.png

Any suggestions?, pseudo-code could help, method of execution would be fantastic.

Comment: If ID & Month are the composite Primary Key then you won't get a duplicate problem - same ID for the following month.  As long as you only have one record per employee per month it'll be ok.

Comment: yes but how do i go about polling new_leave from the previous month to current_leave of the current month?

Comment: Is `Month` just a number from 1 - 12 (in which case month 1 needs to look at month 12 of previous year)?  An actual date?  Text?

Comment: i stored it as short text so i can type it as 01, 02, 03...etc

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a year field so I will assume that your months are not calendar months but instead just months in employment or something like that. In that case, if the month was a proper number you could just use:

NZ(DLookup("New_Leave","TableName","[Month]=" & [Month]-1),0)

If you don't want to change your design to make month a proper number you will have to deal with converting text to number:

NZ(DLookup("New_Leave","TableName","CInt([Month])=" & CInt([Month])-1),0)

This will fail if your text month field does not represent a proper number.

If you are 100% sure that a previous month will always exist (unlikely when Month=1) you could do away with the `Nz` part.

Having said all that, I think your overall design is seriously flawed. The proper way to address your problem is to have a table with EmployeeID, Date, LeaveAmount (where negative represents leave earned or a separate Yes/No field to represent that). This is the only static information you need. Everything else should be calculated as needed in forms/reports and not in your tables.

Comment: i plan on archiving the table every year, so months will only count to 12 then get reset, as for the design part, it may be flawed, i'm still prototyping, employees accumulate earned leaves and incur absences every month, so there has to be a record of these "transactions" besides the final report, simplest thing i could do is just keep updating the current leaves of every employee and call it a day, but i need records.

Comment: Look at my solution again. It is exactly these transactions that you need records on that I suggest you put in your table, it their purest form (no calculated or accumulated data). If your month resets at 12 it is a bit more complicated. You can't just use `[Month]-1`. You need something like `IIF([Month]=1,12,[Month]-1)` to get the previous month.